# HTML CSS Navbar stays at bottom of content unintentionally

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm currently making a navbar for my school's NJROTC program. However, when I add content, the content goes *above* the navbar, even though it's position is fixed and it's top position is set to 0px.

#### Code

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SKHS NJROTC - Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/root.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-left">
                <h1 class="nav-left__brand">NJ<span>ROTC</span></h1>
                <div class="nav-left__links">
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-link" aria-label="Issues Link" title="Issues">Issues</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-link" aria-label="Promotions Link" title="Promotions">Promotions</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-link" aria-label="Events Link" title="Events">Events</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-button" aria-label="Create a new issue, promotion request, or event." title="Create an issue, event, or promotion request.">Create</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-right">
                <div class="nav-right__app__drawer">
                    <span class="material-symbols-sharp">apps</span>
               </div>
                <div class="nav-right__profile"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <span class="directory">Charlie Company » Red Platoon » Promotions</span>
    </header>
    <main>
        lorem
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

src/styles/root.css

```css
@import "./modules/navigation.css";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jura:wght@300;400;600&family=Orbitron:wght@500&display=swap');

:root {
    --accent-color: navy;
    --heading-font-families: 'Orbitron', monospace, sans-serif;
    --body-font-families: 'Jura', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

src/styles/modules/navigation.css

```css
nav {
    font-family: var(--heading-font-families);
    text-transform: uppercase;

    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CECECE;
    padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    justify-content: space-between;

    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

nav .nav-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    gap: 25px;
    align-items: center;
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__brand {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__brand span {
    color: var(--accent-color);
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links {
    flex: 2;
    display: flex;
    gap: 25px;
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links .nav-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: var(--accent-color);
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links .nav-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links .nav-button {
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: var(--accent-color);
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header span.directory {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: var(--heading-font-families);
    color: #CECECE;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I can't figure out my problem. Is it something I simply overlooked? Thanks.

#### Current:

Currently, content in the header (not styled) and other page content in other sections are appearing **above** the navbar.
[image of current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSmG5.png)

#### Expected:

Content not inside `nav` tag appear **below** navigation content, and have navbar stay at top of page.
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCsFl.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you set your `nav` position to `fixed`, it gets out of the normal flow and won't make any spacing. Just wrap everything outside the nav inside a `div`, and set that div's position to `relative` and `top: ` to whatever the size of your `nav` is. @evatrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*it's position is fixed and it's top position is set to 0px.*

That's actually the problem, why did you make it `fixed`? Removind those 2 lines fixed the problem.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jura:wght@300;400;600&family=Orbitron:wght@500&display=swap');

:root {
    --accent-color: navy;
    --heading-font-families: 'Orbitron', monospace, sans-serif;
    --body-font-families: 'Jura', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav {
    font-family: var(--heading-font-families);
    text-transform: uppercase;

    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CECECE;
    padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

nav .nav-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    gap: 25px;
    align-items: center;
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__brand {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__brand span {
    color: var(--accent-color);
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links {
    flex: 2;
    display: flex;
    gap: 25px;
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links .nav-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: var(--accent-color);
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links .nav-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
}

nav .nav-left .nav-left__links .nav-button {
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: var(--accent-color);
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header span.directory {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: var(--heading-font-families);
    color: #CECECE;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SKHS NJROTC - Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/root.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-left">
                <h1 class="nav-left__brand">NJ<span>ROTC</span></h1>
                <div class="nav-left__links">
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-link" aria-label="Issues Link" title="Issues">Issues</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-link" aria-label="Promotions Link" title="Promotions">Promotions</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-link" aria-label="Events Link" title="Events">Events</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nav-button" aria-label="Create a new issue, promotion request, or event." title="Create an issue, event, or promotion request.">Create</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-right">
                <div class="nav-right__app__drawer">
                    <span class="material-symbols-sharp">apps</span>
               </div>
                <div class="nav-right__profile"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <span class="directory">Charlie Company » Red Platoon » Promotions</span>
    </header>
    <main>
        lorem
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made position fixed so that it stays at the top of the page on scroll. I could use sticky position, though. Thank you for the answer!